# Feature or Bug Request

Tags: discussion, moderators

Can we flag questions to be edited by users who understand the math level that the question was asked? Like if a question was asked in real analysis and they know the language, and syntax of the question type. I hope you understand what I mean, because sometimes the edit queue does not draw enough attention to posts that could just be required an edit in mathjax, and it can thus be solved instead of being closed.Maybe Start a chat room for Need Edit Questions, and not the micro edits people do just for appeal. Funnel the questions in there because then its just a matter of programming. We Have golden badge or whatever it is when you earn a tag users. Make use of the system we have in place already.

Comment: How do you find such users?  Adding a flag would be the easy part, but who is vetting the ability of users?  And assuming you find them (let's say you insist they have a bronze badge or better in a suitable tag) how do you get them to review these questions?

Comment: @postmortes Maybe Start a chat room for Need Edit Questions, and not the micro edits people do just for appeal. Funnel the questions in there because then its just a matter of programming. We Have golden badge or whatever it is when you earn a tag users. Make use of the system we have in place already this can be considered an append to my question.

Comment: I would suggest adding all of those thoughts to your question here :)

Comment: Do you suggest to create another review queue, associated with a new flag, to point editing problems? Not a bad idea (especially if close votes are used to flag editing problems, which should not be their purpose IMO). But I don't see why it would be necessary to ask only people with enough ability (always an implicit assumption here). And I don't see either how it's related to the edit queue (which is for validating edits that were already made).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes it saves time of having all these run arounds of oh this is a bad question how long does it take a user to learn mathjax, you think they are going to spend 1 hour to master a new language to come up with a perfect post it takes time, and if they have posts done by expert users when they key word fresh on the site then that helps other wise if its a habitual person posting low quality posts no effort then close it the tutorial is on meta... so thats goes as far for my point.

Comment: I tend to agree. I had my first contact with LaTeX almost 20 years ago, and it was painful at first (but later it was actually really enjoyable to be able to display equations nicely). I won't vote to close a question only because of LaTeX: if it's missing, I write the code, problem solved, period. Newbies need to be helped here. However I'm not as friendly with users who have been here for some time: learning LaTeX is also part of the job of everyone here, and it's especially easy to learn by example.

Comment: That said, yes, I would be in favor of a new tag for editing problems, which are by the way not limited to LaTeX: photos of poor quality drawings, foreign language to translate to english, or even english to improve, mathematical wording to improve, etc. Or even some technical problems (there was once a case of an image with transparency problems, for instance). To me, these are not good reasons to close, provided the OP has otherwise shown he has put some thought in the question.

Comment: Such a tag would be only for someone who is able to see there is a problem (maybe even the OP), while unable to solve it himself.

Comment: Now, try and convince the community...